# How to contact moderators

Tags: support, moderators

Is there a way to communicate with the moderators on ELL?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to contact a mod in private is to flag one of your posts and ask them to create a private room for you. However, you can use the contact link on any page to contact community managers, too.

Answer (score 3):

There are several.

You have already found one, although meta is not exactly ideal for discussions you wish to have *exclusively* with the diamonds.

You can also start a gallery chat room (you have more than enough rep) and go with that; others can see it if they happen to pass by, but the rubbernecking is likely to be much less significant.

Or you can just flag some suitable post with the action you want them to take, if that's applicable. (If there's a lot of details you need to add to the request, you can use a deleted answer to carry the extra text that doesn't fit in the flag dialog, then flag that answer. Deleted questions cannot be edited, otherwise I'd suggest that.)

Comment: I have been on the receiving end of numerous unjustified disciplinary actions lately.

Comment: @meatie: Not being a mod, I can't and won't speculate on the justifications, but "numerous" and "lately" do not seem to work well together. Suspensions aren't really going to be handed out by the dozen in 2-day stretches. Perhaps you meant something besides mod discipline?

Comment: @meatie What do you consider a disciplinary action? Closing a question or deleting a comment is site maintenance, not an action taken to punish a user.