# Is there a way to talk privately to a moderator?

Tags: support, moderators, moderation

A situation has come to my attention that I feel needs moderator intervention.

Drawing attention to the situation might make it worse, so I would like to speak privately to a moderator. Is the some way to do this?

Comment: Related: [How do I privately contact the moderators?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4944/9161) and [How to contact moderators](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2703/91610)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, leaving no publicly visible trail at all: flag a post (on of your own or one that is involved in the matter you want to discuss) and state you want to chat with us privately. We'll then open a private chatroom as AIQ says.

Yet another way, since you have [100 reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms), is to create a chatroom and invite one of the moderators. That moderator can then make the room private.

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is. Drop by in the ELL chatroom, and then say this exact same thing there. A moderator will open a private chatroom for you and them.